# Writing remote JSON result to local file

Tags: php, json, save

I am using a reverse whois API to get a JSON array of domain names registered to a specific person. I want to get this array and save it into a file locally every 24 hours (using cron). How do I go about saving the result from the API to a local file?

So far I have this:

```
<?php

public function get_url($request_url) {

$curl_handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);  
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); 
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $JsonResponse = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    $http_code = curl_getinfo($curl_handle);

  return($JsonResponse);
}


$file = 'cm.json';
file_put_contents($file, mixed get_url("http://api.whoxy.com/?key=apikey&reverse=whois&name=Value+Name"));
?>
```

How do I get this working? I have limited knowledge of JSON and PHP, give me some tips?

Comment: try removing that `mixed`, no idea what that's doing there

Comment: Just noticed this: Why do you get `$http_code` and then not do anything with it? It doesn't break your code, but still.

Comment: even try getting rid of the curl altogether, and try just using `$json = file_get_contents($url);`

Comment: KIKO, that's to check he gets an HTTP 200 response. He isn't checking it though

Comment: @delboy1978uk: That's what I thought. It would be a good argument for using PHP: If the API ever changes, and doesn't work anymore (which will happen), you could, for instance, send yourself an email warning about this. If you use pure cron/curl you have to check the logs.

Comment: So would `file_get_contents($file, $url);` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's cron, no need to use PHP at all, just use curl from shell command:

```
curl --fail "http://api.whoxy.com/?key=apikey&reverse=whois&name=Value+Name" -o cm.json
```

Comment: Interesting, but isn't this unsafe? For example, what if the response is not 200? What if API key is changed? etc.

Comment: you can use `--fail` flag to avoid downloading the file on non-200 code.

Comment: if you want to make it "safe", you need to set up some kind of monitoring to make sure that the cron job has successfully been run and the file has been updated. Normally if cronjob fails you would get an internal mail message on the system.